# Replacing vowels from user input with special characters from an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

Hello Stack Overflow users,
I am trying to replace vowels in the user input with different characters. The first method below enhances a password passed in as a String parameter by replacing every vowel with a designated special character. The only issue I have is when printing in the main, I need for the entered password to have vowels replaced. For example, if "hello" is entered, then "h3ll0" should print. The return statement for the second method has something to do with this, but I am not sure. If there is any advice that anyone can provide, that would be much appreciated.

```
 public static String enhancePassword(String oldPassword)
{
    String vowel []= {"a","e","i","o","u"};
    String newVowel []= {"@","3","!","0","^"};
    String newPassword="";
    String newValue="";

    for(int i=0;i<=oldPassword.length();i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<=vowel.length-1;j++) {
            newValue=replaceCharacter(oldPassword, vowel[j],newVowel[j]); 
        }
    }

    return newPassword;
}
```

This method takes a given String and searches it for a given
character.

```
public static String replaceCharacter
(String password, String toBeReplaced, String replacementCharacter)
{
    int move= password.length()-1;
    int counter=0;
    String string2="";

    for(string2 = password.substring(move, password.length()-counter); move>=0; move--) {
        if(string2.equals(toBeReplaced)) {
            string2=replacementCharacter;
        }
        else {
            string2=password.substring(move+1, password.length()-counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return string2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks too complex. I suggest to use something like this

```
public static String enhancePassword(String oldPassword) {
    String vowel[] = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };
    String newVowel[] = { "@", "3", "!", "0", "^" };
    for (int i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        oldPassword = oldPassword.replaceAll(vowel[i], newVowel[i]);
    }
    return oldPassword;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where is the  check to see char at i is a vowel?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani, I'm looping vowels array.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev That's awesome. Thank you for helping. Works great!